# MongoDB systemctl start failure due to dbpath/keyfile path permission error

Tags: linux, mongodb, redhat

I have a working mongodb instance that can be run using `mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf` but it shows systemctl service as failed.

I tried to start it using `sudo service mongod start` and it fails with `exitcode=1`

I figured out the permission errors and changed permission of each dbpath and keyfile path by `sudo chown -R mongod:root`  and then it started working under root

I wanna know why it didn't work even under root when dbpath and keyfile path permissions were `mongod:mongod` and

How to assign directory permission if I want to run `systemctl mongod` without root access?

**OS - RHEL 8 , mongod version 5.0**

`mongod.conf` file

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

storage:
  dbPath: /data/mongodb/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true

processManagement:
  fork: true  
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: mongo3.xxxxxxx.net  

security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /data/key/keyfile

replication:
  replSetName: xxxxx
```

Comment: Please show us your `mongod.conf` file and have a look at the mongo log file (typically at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`)

Comment: What are the file permissions for the key file `/data/key/keyfile`? It must not have group or world permissions, i.e. run `chmod 600 /data/key/keyfile`. Also `bindIp: mongo3.xxxxxxx.net` looks strange. It should contain at least the localhost and all replica set member hosts.

Comment: already did ``chmod 600``. I have edited the ``/etc/hosts`` file to assign ``0.0.0.0,::`` to this dns. ``keyfile`` also has ``mongod:root`` permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system I start the service with `sudo systemctl start mongod`

You can set everything in the service file, could be like this:

```
$ systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-06 16:41:02 CEST; 1 weeks 1 days ago


$ cat /etc/systemd/system/mongod.service
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /data/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /data/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /data/mongodb
PermissionsStartOnly=true
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
Type=forking
```

Note, when you install MongoDB then it creates a default service file at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`. You should not modify this file, it might be overwritten by your package manager at next update. Instead put your customized file at `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224992/where-do-i-put-my-systemd-unit-file) - and don't forget `systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: It works very well with sudo priviledge but only after I changed dbpath and keyfile path permissions to mongod:root. By default installation it was mongod:mongod and it failed to start even as with root priviledge.