# mongod shows failed to start

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am new to mongoDB. After installation this commard was working fine but it's throwing this error now.

After starting MongoDB the `systemctl status mongod` command shows that `mongod.service` has failed to start.

```
debdwaipayan@debbiswas-ideapad3:~$ sudo systemctl start mongod

debdwaipayan@debbiswas-ideapad3:~$ sudo systemctl status mongod

● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server

     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-06-17 13:30:37 IST; 4s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 5786 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
   Main PID: 5786 (code=exited, status=14)

     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-06-17 13:30:37 IST; 4s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 5786 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
   Main PID: 5786 (code=exited, status=14)

Jun 17 13:30:37 debbiswas-ideapad3 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.

Jun 17 13:30:37 debbiswas-ideapad3 mongod[5786]: {"t":{"$date":"2023-06-17T08:0>

Jun 17 13:30:37 debbiswas-ideapad3 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a

Jun 17 13:30:37 debbiswas-ideapad3 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Have a log at the mongo log file. Location is defined in config file `/etc/mongod.conf`, typically `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`. Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187641/mongodb-systemctl-start-failure-due-to-dbpath-keyfile-path-permission-error/69187822#69187822

Comment: Possibly related?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/823288/mongodb-loads-but-breaks-returning-status-14