# MongoDB cannot start

Tags: mongodb, centos, pymongo, centos7

I encounter such an error when starting mongodb, the following result

```
systemctl status mongod.service
```

when I use the command :

```
     mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-12-22 16:36:41 +03; 2s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 1525 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=14)
  Process: 1522 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1520 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1518 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 22 16:36:40 86233-56428 systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Dec 22 16:36:41 86233-56428 mongod[1525]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready...ons.
Dec 22 16:36:41 86233-56428 mongod[1525]: forked process: 1528
Dec 22 16:36:41 86233-56428 mongod[1525]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 14
Dec 22 16:36:41 86233-56428 mongod[1525]: To see additional information in this output, start withou...ion.
Dec 22 16:36:41 86233-56428 systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=14
Dec 22 16:36:41 86233-56428 systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
Dec 22 16:36:41 86233-56428 systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Dec 22 16:36:41 86233-56428 systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

I am encountering this error.

I tried many solutions here but they don't work. I changed the file permissions and it still didn't work. I reinstalled and still the same result.

These are /var/log/mongod.log records

```
2023-12-22T17:17:28.660+0300 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2023-12-22T17:17:28.678+0300 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2023-12-22T17:17:28.836+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1049 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=86233-56428
2023-12-22T17:17:28.836+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.28
2023-12-22T17:17:28.836+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: af1a9dc12adcfa83cc19571cb3faba26eeddac92
2023-12-22T17:17:28.836+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2023-12-22T17:17:28.836+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2023-12-22T17:17:28.836+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2023-12-22T17:17:28.836+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2023-12-22T17:17:28.836+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: rhel70
2023-12-22T17:17:28.836+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2023-12-22T17:17:28.836+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2023-12-22T17:17:28.837+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid", timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2023-12-22T17:17:28.848+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /var/lib/mongo, terminating
2023-12-22T17:17:28.848+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] Shutdown started
2023-12-22T17:17:28.848+0300 I REPL     [initandlisten] Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown, waitTime: 10000ms
2023-12-22T17:17:28.848+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2023-12-22T17:17:28.848+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2023-12-22T17:17:28.848+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] Shutting down the global connection pool
2023-12-22T17:17:28.848+0300 I -        [initandlisten] Killing all operations for shutdown
2023-12-22T17:17:28.848+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor
2023-12-22T17:17:28.848+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] Shutting down free monitoring
2023-12-22T17:17:28.849+0300 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Shutting down full-time data capture
2023-12-22T17:17:28.849+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Shutting down the HealthLog
2023-12-22T17:17:28.849+0300 I -        [initandlisten] Dropping the scope cache for shutdown
2023-12-22T17:17:28.849+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2023-12-22T17:17:28.849+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Comment: Have a look at the mongo logfile, typically `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I added the topic, forgot to add it, I apologize.

Comment: Looks like you try to start the service although it is already running. Why do you run an outdated version of MongoDB?

Comment: the service is not working. I made the entire project based on this version.

Comment: See error message: "read-only directory: /var/lib/mongo" - You need to grant write privileges on this folder. You may change owner and permission in the service file.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Actually, I think I have given the necessary permissions, all permissions are 755, but could there be a problem with ownership? Currently the owner appears to be "mongod".

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187641/mongodb-systemctl-start-failure-due-to-dbpath-keyfile-path-permission-error/69187822#69187822 - it creates folder, set owner and permissions.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Finally I solved it. The owner of some files appeared to be "mongod" and some others appeared to be "mongodb" and "root". I changed all the necessary files to "mongod" as they should be and it worked, now it works without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/exit-codes) will help you self-diagnose the exit codes you are seeing (14 & 100) in the future.

The relevant exception is listed in your question. The `--dbpath` directory does not exist with correct permissions for the user trying to run the binary.

Since you are running under `systemctl`, look to the configuration of that service. By default, it will use root for a system service. Consider running `mongod` as a non-root user, and ensure the `dbpath` directory has write permissions of that user. Relevant MongoDB [docs page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/configuration/).